# Using Shared memory in Posix Semaphore wait and signal in C

Tags: c, posix, semaphore, shared-memory

Using this code below as an example. The code stops after printing waiting until stop the program manually, but doesn't signal the next function. I checked it multiple times (even removing the mutual exclusion) and discovered that being inside the `for` or `while` is what causes the problem.

According to other users, I must use **shared memory** to get this working, but I don't know how to use it or apply it to this specific code.

I've looked at many websites to better understand this situation such as https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/posix-shared-memory-api/

The most recommended I've seen is `shmget()` and `mmap()`.

So the question, how can I get `sem_wait()` to work inside of any type of loop using Shared memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/shm.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
sem_t *mutex; 
void wait_t(int a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a < 0)
        {
            sem_wait(&mutex);
            printf("waiting\n"); //Stops here due lack of shared memory
        }
        a--;
    }
}

void signal_t(int a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a <= 0)
        {
            printf("signal\n");
            sem_post(&mutex);
        }
        a++;
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    int shared_mem_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), IPC_CREAT);
    mutex = shmat(shared_mem_id, NULL, 0);
    sem_init(&mutex, 1, 1);
    int i = -2;
    if(fork() == 0){ // create 1st child process
        mutex = shmat(shared_mem_id, NULL, 0);
        wait_t(i);
        exit(0);
        shmdt(mutex);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    if(fork() == 0){ // create 2nd child process
        mutex = shmat(shared_mem_id, NULL, 0);
        signal_t(i);
        exit(0);
        shmdt(mutex);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    if(fork() == 0){ // create 3nd child process
        mutex = shmat(shared_mem_id, NULL, 0);
        signal_t(i);
        exit(0);
        shmdt(mutex);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    exit(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the idea is that your parent process would need to create a new shared memory space:

```
shared_mem_id = shmemget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), IPC_CREAT);
```

Then all the processes needing access to the semaphore will need to do:

```
sem_t *mutex = shmat(shared_mem_id, NULL, 0);
```

(So you'll need to do this in each child process, after the fork)

And then the functions that use the semaphore will need to have access to the mutex pointer (remember to add a dereference to mutex).

Once they are done, each process using the mutex will need to do:

```
shmdt(mutex);
```

Of course, you can feel free to store more complex structures in the shared memory as long as you allocate enough space.

Comment: So I have to put `sem_t *mutex = shmat(shared_mem_id, NULL, 0);` in all the `if(fork() == 0)`?

Comment: I think it's `IPC_CREAT`, not `IPC_CREATE`.

Comment: Yes, sorry typo, it's IPC_CREAT.
And yes, the `fork() == 0 ` branches will all need a call to shmat() to get access to the memory.
You probably will to do it once in the parent as well to initialize the semaphore.

Comment: I've made the edits to the code, following your instructions. I'm not sure if I did it right though.

Comment: From a quick glance, after the shmget() and before the sem_init(), you need to do:
`mutex = shmat(shared_mem_id, NULL, 0);`as well.

Also, wait_t and signal_t function shouldn't call shmdt, shmdt should only be called to "remove" the memory from the process, once the process will no longer use it.

Comment: Okay test 2, removed shmdt from functions and placed `mutex = shmat(shared_mem_id, NULL, 0);` between shmget() and before sem_init(). It does compile properly.

Comment: Well, you should do the testing on your own before replying here.
Does the program compile? If not, can you fix it on your own? If not, explain here what are the issues.
Does the program run as expected? If not, can you find the solution on your own? If not, explain what you are struggling with.

Otherwise it's hard to guess what you expect as a reply.

Comment: I've compile and tested it and it works. However I don't think shmdt is properly implemented. Waiting and Signal are printed three times per process. I understand that fork() duplicates processes into two (parent and child).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213329/discussion-between-julien-thierry-and-zam-oxy).

Comment: what do I do if I want to share a variable across these functions, such a length for the for loops. The function can change them and then share to the next function and hold same value. I can't use global variables or other values because that value would be the same as when it was first initialized, not when changed in the functions.